# Cannot create new account with PHP script

Tags: php

I'm struggling with the following webpage which belongs to a Gameserver to create a new account within the SQL Database. Now the problem is, for some reason, as soon as I click the register button, nothing happens. With the Developer tool I've found out an error message will be thrown as soon as Register has been clicked.
This is the error message :
Fatal error: uncaught Error. Non static method Database::getData() cannot be called statically in (.... pathname)

Kind regards,

Chris

I Already tried some sollutions mentioned on the internet.
For example to replace the Database::getData() to $Databse->getData() but this does not seem to work, or i'm doing something wrong.

This is my register.php file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
include_once('config/database.php');
include_once('config/config.php');
include_once('config/helper.php');

$config = new Config();
$request_params = getRequests();

$submitted_username = '';
$alert_message = '';
$relative_path = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    // Get user by username
    $db_user = $config->db_user;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.TblAccount WHERE accountid = '$username'";
    $user_data  =  Database::getData($db_user, $sql, 'row');
    //$user_data = $dbName->getData($db_user, $sql, 'row');  <--- this I've tested.
    // Check password
    if ($user_data) {
        echo 0;
        die;
    }else{
        $hash_password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $db_user = $config->db_user;
        $sql = "EXEC dbo.regnewaccount '$username','$hash_password'";
        $user_data  = Database::getData($db_user, $sql, 'row');
        echo 1;
        die;
    }
}
?>
```

(Edit: This is the current Database.php script)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

        
class Database
{
        private static $cont  = 'null';
    
    public function __construct() {
        exit('Init function is not allowed');
    }

    public static  function connect($db_data) {
        $dbName = $db_data['database'];
        $dbHost = $db_data['hostname'];
        $dbUsername = $db_data['username'];
        $dbUserPassword = $db_data['password'];
        $dbDriver = $db_data['dbdriver'];

        // One connection through whole application
        if ( null == self::$cont ) {
            try {
                switch($dbDriver){
                    case 'sqlsrv':
                        self::$cont = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$dbHost."; Database=".$dbName.";", $dbUsername, $dbUserPassword);  
                        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
                        break;
                    default:
                        self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".$dbHost.";"."dbname=".$dbName. ";charset=utf8", $dbUsername, $dbUserPassword);
                        break;
                }
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        return self::$cont;
    }

    public static function disconnect() {
        self::$cont = null;
    }

    public static function getData($db_data, $sql,$type="list"){
        self::connect($db_data);
        switch($type){
            case 'row':
                $raw_data = self::$cont->query($sql)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
            default:
                $raw_data = self::$cont->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                break;
        }
        self::disconnect();
        return $raw_data;
    }

    public function updateData($db_data, $sql){
        self::connect($db_data);
        $raw_data = self::$cont->exec($sql);
        self::disconnect();
        return $raw_data;
    }
}

?>
```

This is the Config.php file, which contains the credentials for the SQL connections.

```
<?php
class Config
{
    const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = '20';
    const RELATIVE_URL = '';

    public $db_data;
    public $db_mulegend_jp;

    public function __construct() {
        $db_data['dbdriver'] = 'sqlsrv';
        $db_data['hostname'] = '192.168.XXX.XXX';
        $db_data['username'] = 'USER';
        $db_data['password'] = 'TEST';
        $db_data['database'] = 'Mu2Auth';
        

        $db_mulegend_jp['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $db_mulegend_jp['username'] = 'root';
        $db_mulegend_jp['password'] = 'TEST';
        $db_mulegend_jp['database'] = 'mulegend_jp';
        $db_mulegend_jp['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

        $this->db_user = $db_user;
        $this->db_mulegend_jp = $db_mulegend_jp;
      }

}
```

Comment: You need to define get data as static function to call it with class definition.

Comment: Don't know what's in `$config->db_user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `static` keyword here

```php
public static function getData() { ... }
```

Then you will be able to access it like:

```php
Database::getData(...);
```

The method should be static because you are trying to access other static methods inside it.

Comment: It seems it is starting to work now, at least that errormessage is gone now. Now I have to figure out why the SQL connection is not working. SQLSTATE[HY000 [1045] Access denied for user "@localhost" using password: NO

Comment: @Chris which database server is giving error? If MSSQL then you need to install odbc or obdc driver and also PHP sqlsrv extensions. I don't remember correctly but these things need to be installed for mssql to work with PHP.

Comment: Well your error message should contain a user name like "user@localhost" and using password should be YES instead of NO. Please check the connection strings.

Comment: $pdo = new PDO(
        "sqlsrv:Server=DESKTOP-PV0H4GU\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Shopee",
        "root",
        "root",
        [PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]
    ); //
This has been my code for MSSQL server.

Comment: For some reason the php script is not calling the MSSQL server. Instead it falls back every time on the MySQL server that is also running for another part of the database. I Already tried to install the drivers in XAMPP for sqlsrv and PDO, but for some reason it keeps falling back on the MySQL server. As you can see in the database script above, the username and password for the database has been defined as a string, so should be used for all the connections to the database.

Comment: Do you have ODBC driver installed?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also you have defined dbDriver as `MSSQL` but in switch you are using `sqlsrv` which will make it always fallback to default case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Also tried to change the dbDriver to sqlsrv, but this also does not seem to work. I've installed the ODBC driver you mentioned also, but for some reason, it only tries to connect to the MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the phpinfo also, and it looks like all the drivers and extensions are loaded.

[PHPINFO()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pdsV.png)

I don't know if something else is wrong in the Database PHP code, but it looks like it is still ignoring the sqlsrv part.
ODBC Drivers also have been installed.

I've even tried to replace the line with the server address to :

`private static $dbHost = '192.168.XXX.XXX, 1443 ' ;`

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tk6JW.png)

It looks like somehow, the defined server and credentials are not read from the file.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

class Database
{
    private static $dbName = 'Mu2Auth' ;
    private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
    private static $dbUsername = 'XX';
    private static $dbUserPassword = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    private static $dbdriver = 'sqlsrv';  //<--- not sure if nessecary
    private static $cont  = null;
```

Comment: In the meanwhile, i think i've gotten a step further with the server, but it still is throwing some errors. I've removed the login details and Database address from the Database.php file, as they're used from the config.php file, which contains the login details already for both databases. (sqlsrv and mysql). 

The following line has been adjusted : `private static $cont  = null; ` to `private static $cont  = 'null';` 

The new problem is : 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string in C:\MuServer\wwwroot\api\config\database.php on line 48

Any Ideas ?